# How do I show that kinetic energy changes observed from two different inertial frames are the same?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, inertial-frames

This is from MIT OpenCourseWare, 2.003SC Engineering Dynamics, problem set #1, concept question #6. The situation is: given a fixed reference frame $O$, there are two cars having mass $m_1 = 1000 kg$ and $m_2 = 2000 kg$ moving with velocity $v_{1/O} = 25\hat i$ and $v_{2/O} = -25\hat i$ respectively. The two cars then collides head on and stick together with a velocity $v_{3/O}$ (not given). The concept question is: Suppose there is another frame $A$ translating without accelerating with respect to frame $O$, do the momentum and kinetic energy changes observed from two inertial reference frames equal? The question accounts other general situations as well. I got the answer wrong the first time (I thought the momentum changes are equal, but kinetic energy changes are not equal because of the velocity square), turn out the solution is that kinetic energy changes are also equal, but it doesn't show me why. This is a yes or no question; it doesn't ask me to show anything but I want to show it anyway because I am skeptical with the solution (but to think about it I feel the solution makes more sense than my answer). The momentum changes are straighforward;however, I was stuck when I tried to show that the kinetic energy changes are equal.

My approach is to first write the velocty vectors in general terms.

The velocities as observed from frame $O$ are

$\vec v_{1/O} = v_{1x/O}\hat i +v_{1y/O}\hat j +v_{1z/O}\hat k$

$\vec v_{2/O} = v_{2x/O}\hat i +v_{2y/O}\hat j +v_{2z/O}\hat k$

$\vec v_{3/O} = v_{3x/O}\hat i +v_{3y/O}\hat j +v_{3z/O}\hat k$

$\vec v_{A/O} = v_{Ax/O}\hat i +v_{Ay/O}\hat j +v_{Az/O}\hat k$

The velocities as observed from frame $A$ are

$\vec v_{1/A} = \vec v_{1/O} - \vec v_{A/O} = (v_{1x/O}-v_{Ax/O})\hat i +(v_{1y/O}-v_{Ay/O})\hat j +(v_{1z/O}-v_{Az/O})\hat k$

$\vec v_{2/A} = \vec v_{2/O} - \vec v_{A/O} = (v_{2x/O}-v_{Ax/O})\hat i +(v_{2y/O}-v_{Ay/O})\hat j +(v_{2z/O}-v_{Az/O})\hat k$

$\vec v_{3/A} = \vec v_{3/O} - \vec v_{A/O} = (v_{3x/O}-v_{Ax/O})\hat i +(v_{3y/O}-v_{Ay/O})\hat j +(v_{3z/O}-v_{Az/O})\hat k$

**Momentum changes:**

The momenta as observed from frame $O$ is

$\vec p_{1/O} = m_1\vec v_{1/O} = m_1(v_{1x/O}\hat i +v_{1y/O}\hat j +v_{1z/O}\hat k)$

$\vec p_{2/O} = m_2\vec v_{2/O} = m_2(v_{2x/O}\hat i +v_{2y/O}\hat j +v_{2z/O}\hat k)$

$\vec p_{3/O} = (m_1+m_2)\vec v_{3/O} = (m_1+m_2)(v_{3x/O}\hat i +v_{3y/O}\hat j +v_{3z/O}\hat k)$

So, the momentum changes in frame O is

$\Delta \vec p_{/O} = \vec p_{3/O} - \vec p_{2/O} - \vec p_{1/O} = m_1(v_{3x/O}-v_{1x/O})\hat i +m_1(v_{3y/O}-v_{1y/O})\hat j +m_1(v_{3z/O}-v_{1z/O})\hat k +m_2(v_{3x/O}-v_{2x/O})\hat i +m_2(v_{3y/O}-v_{2y/O})\hat j +m_2(v_{3z/O}-v_{2z/O})\hat k$

The momenta as observed from frame $A$ is

$\vec p_{1/A} = m_1\vec v_{1/A} = m_1((v_{1x/O}-v_{Ax/O})\hat i +(v_{1y/O}-v_{Ay/O})\hat j +(v_{1z/O}-v_{Az/O})\hat k))$

$\vec p_{2/A} = m_2\vec v_{2/A} = m_2((v_{2x/O}-v_{Ax/O})\hat i +(v_{2y/O}-v_{Ay/O})\hat j +(v_{2z/O}-v_{Az/O})\hat k))$

$\vec p_{3/A} = (m_1+m_2)\vec v_{3/A} = (m_1+m_2)((v_{3x/O}-v_{Ax/O})\hat i +(v_{3y/O}-v_{Ay/O})\hat j +(v_{3z/O}-v_{Az/O})\hat k))$

So the momentum change in frame $A$ is

$\Delta \vec p_{/A} = \vec p_{3/A} - \vec p_{2/A} - \vec p_{1/A} = m_1(v_{3x/O}-v_{1x/O})\hat i +m_1(v_{3y/O}-v_{1y/O})\hat j +m_1(v_{3z/O}-v_{1z/O})\hat k +m_2(v_{3x/O}-v_{2x/O})\hat i +m_2(v_{3y/O}-v_{2y/O})\hat j +m_2(v_{3z/O}-v_{2z/O})\hat k$

It can be seen clearly that the momentum changes as observed from frame $O$ and $A$ are equal $\Delta \vec p_{/O} = \Delta \vec p_{/A}$.

**Kinetic energy changes:**

Kinetic energies observed from fixed frame $O$

$T_{1/O} = \frac12 m_1 ||\vec v_{1/O}||^2 = \frac12 m_1 (v_{1x/O}^2 + v_{1y/O}^2 + v_{1z/O}^2)$

$T_{2/O} = \frac12 m_2 ||\vec v_{2/O}||^2 = \frac12 m_2 (v_{2x/O}^2 + v_{2y/O}^2 + v_{2z/O}^2)$

$T_{3/O} = \frac12 (m_1+m_2) ||\vec v_{3/O}||^2 = \frac12 (m_1+m_2) (v_{3x/O}^2 + v_{3y/O}^2 + v_{3z/O}^2)$

So, the kinetic energy change in frame $O$ is

$\Delta T_{/O} = T_{3/O}-T_{1/O}-T_{2/O}$

$\Delta T_{/O} = \frac12 m_1 (v_{3x/O}^2-v_{1x/O}^2) + \frac12 m_1 (v_{3y/O}^2-v_{1y/O}^2) + \frac12 m_1 (v_{3z/O}^2-v_{1z/O}^2) + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3x/O}^2-v_{2x/O}^2) + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3y/O}^2-v_{2y/O}^2) + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3z/O}^2-v_{2z/O}^2)$

Kinetic energies observed from fixed frame $A$

$T_{1/A} = \frac12 m_1 ||\vec v_{1/A}||^2 = \frac12 m_1 ||\vec v_{1/O} - \vec v_{A/O}||^2 = \frac12 m_1 ((v_{1x/O}-v_{Ax/O})^2 + (v_{1y/O}-v_{Ay/O})^2 + (v_{1z/O}-v_{Az/O})^2)$

$T_{2/A} = \frac12 m_2 ||v_{2/A}||^2 = \frac12 m_2 ||\vec v_{2/O} - \vec v_{A/O}||^2 =  \frac12 m_2 ((v_{2x/O}-v_{Ax/O})^2 + (v_{2y/O}-v_{Ay/O})^2 + (v_{2z/O}-v_{Az/O})^2)$

$T_{3/A} = \frac12 (m_1+m_2) ||v_{3/A}||^2 = \frac12 (m_1+m_2) ||\vec v_{3/O} - \vec v_{A/O}||^2 =  \frac12 (m_1+m_2) ((v_{3x/O}-v_{Ax/O})^2 + (v_{3y/O}-v_{Ay/O})^2 + (v_{3z/O}-v_{Az/O})^2)$

So, the kinetic enegy changes as observed from frame $A$ is

$\Delta T_{/A} = T_{3/A}-T_{1/A}-T_{2/A}$

$\Delta T_{/A} = \frac12 m_1 (v_{3x/O}^2 - 2v_{3x/O}v_{Ax/O} + v_{Ax/O}^2 - v_{1x/O}^2 + 2v_{1x/O}v_{Ax/O} - v_{Ax/O}^2) + \frac12 m_1 (v_{3y/O}^2 - 2v_{3y/O}v_{Ay/O} + v_{Ay/O}^2 - v_{1y/O}^2 + 2v_{1y/O}v_{Ay/O} - v_{Ay/O}^2) + \frac12 m_1 (v_{3z/O}^2 - 2v_{3z/O}v_{Az/O} + v_{Az/O}^2 - v_{1z/O}^2 + 2v_{1z/O}v_{Az/O} - v_{Az/O}^2) + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3x/O}^2 - 2v_{3x/O}v_{Ax/O} + v_{Ax/O}^2 - v_{2x/O}^2 + 2v_{2x/O}v_{Ax/O} - v_{Ax/O}^2) + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3y/O}^2 - 2v_{3y/O}v_{Ay/O} + v_{Ay/O}^2 - v_{2y/O}^2 + 2v_{2y/O}v_{Ay/O} - v_{Ay/O}^2) + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3z/O}^2 - 2v_{3z/O}v_{Az/O} + v_{Az/O}^2 - v_{2z/O}^2 + 2v_{2z/O}v_{Az/O} - v_{Az/O}^2)$

$\Delta T_{/A} = \frac12 m_1 (v_{3x/O}^2 - 2v_{3x/O}v_{Ax/O} - v_{1x/O}^2 + 2v_{1x/O}v_{Ax/O}) + ... + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3z/O}^2 - 2v_{3z/O}v_{Az/O} - v_{2z/O}^2 + 2v_{2z/O}v_{Az/O})$

$\Delta T_{/A} = \frac12 m_1 (v_{3x/O}^2  - v_{1x/O}^2 - 2v_{Ax/O} (v_{3x/O}-v_{1x/O})) + ... + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3z/O}^2  - v_{2z/O}^2 - 2v_{Az/O} (v_{3z/O}-v_{2z/O}))$

$\Delta T_{/A} = \frac12 m_1 ((v_{3x/O}  + v_{1x/O})(v_{3x/O}  - v_{1x/O}) - 2v_{Ax/O} (v_{3x/O}-v_{1x/O})) + ... + \frac12 m_2 ((v_{3z/O}  + v_{2z/O})(v_{3z/O}  - v_{2z/O}) - 2v_{Az/O} (v_{3z/O}-v_{2z/O}))$

$\Delta T_{/A} = \frac12 m_1 (v_{3x/O}  - v_{1x/O})(v_{3x/O}+v_{1x/O}-2v_{Ax/O}) + ... + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3z/O}  - v_{2z/O})(v_{3z/O}  + v_{2z/O} - 2v_{Az/O})$

From

$\vec v_{1/A} = \vec v_{1/O} - \vec v_{A/O}$,

$\vec v_{2/A} = \vec v_{2/O} - \vec v_{A/O}$

and $\vec v_{3/A} = \vec v_{3/O} - \vec v_{A/O}$

Then the expression above can be changed to $\Delta T_{/A} = \frac12 m_1 (v_{3x/O}  - v_{1x/O})(v_{3x/A}+v_{1x/A}) + ... + \frac12 m_2 (v_{3z/O}  - v_{2z/O})(v_{3z/A}  + v_{2z/A})$

Now I don't know what to do next to obtain the same expression as $\Delta T_{/O}$ because the second parentheses is speed with respect to $A$ (if they are with respect to $O$ then that would be easy). I might make a mistake somewhere but I couldn't find it, so if anyone could guide me or help me find my mistake I would appreciate your help very much.

Another question that is not in the PSET but I would like to know: are the momentum and kinetic energy changes observed in two accelerating(non-inertial) frames equal?

Answer (score 1):

#### Summary

This missing step in your work is that you need to use the conservation of momentum to finish the proof. Without conservation of momentum, you cannot relate the initial and final velocities in the new frame of reference.

#### Math Section

So as not to get lost in a sea of subscripts, I'm going to use vector notation. The operation $\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_2$ is known as the [dot product or inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition) and is calculated by $\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_2 = v_{1x}v_{2x} + v_{1y}v_{2y} + v_{1z}v_{2z}$. Also, the following are two useful identities:
$$\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v} = ||\vec{v}||^2$$
$$\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b} + \vec{c}) = \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} + \vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}$$

All velocities are in the original $O$ frame.

The change in kinetic energy after shifting to the $A$ frame is
\begin{align}
\Delta T_A &= \frac{1}{2}(m_1 + m_2)||\vec{v}_3 - \vec{v}_A||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_1||\vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_A||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_2||\vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_A||^2 \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}(m_1 + m_2)(||\vec{v}_3||^2 - 2\vec{v}_3\cdot\vec{v}_A + ||\vec{v}_A||^2) - \frac{1}{2}m_1(||\vec{v}_1||^2 - 2\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_A + ||\vec{v}_A||^2) - \frac{1}{2}m_2(||\vec{v}_2||^2 - 2\vec{v}_2\cdot\vec{v}_A + ||\vec{v}_A||^2)
\end{align}
After some rearranging:
\begin{align}
\Delta T_A = &\phantom+\left[\frac{1}{2}(m_1 + m_2)||\vec{v}_3||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_1||\vec{v}_1||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_2||\vec{v}_2||^2\right] \\
&-(m_1 + m_2)\vec{v}_3\cdot\vec{v}_A + m_1\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_A + m_2\vec{v}_2\cdot\vec{v}_A \\
&+ \frac{1}{2}(m_1 + m_2)||\vec{v}_A||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_1||\vec{v}_A||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_2||\vec{v}_A||^2
\end{align}

The first line is the kinetic energy change in the original $O$ frame:
$$\Delta T = \frac{1}{2}(m_1 + m_2)||\vec{v}_3||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_1||\vec{v}_1||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_2||\vec{v}_2||^2$$
So,
\begin{align}
\Delta T_A = &\phantom+\Delta T \\
&-(m_1 + m_2)\vec{v}_3\cdot\vec{v}_A + m_1\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_A + m_2\vec{v}_2\cdot\vec{v}_A \\
&+ \frac{1}{2}(m_1 + m_2)||\vec{v}_A||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_1||\vec{v}_A||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_2||\vec{v}_A||^2
\end{align}

The second line is zero because of conservation of momentum:
$$m_1\vec{v}_1 + m_2\vec{v}_2 = (m_1 + m_2)\vec{v}_3,$$
and dotting both sides with $\vec{v}_A$,
$$m_1\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_A + m_2\vec{v}_2\cdot\vec{v}_A = (m_1 + m_2)\vec{v}_3\cdot\vec{v}_A.$$
This simplifies the equation for $\Delta T_A$ to
\begin{align}
\Delta T_A = &\phantom+\Delta T \\
&+ \frac{1}{2}(m_1 + m_2)||\vec{v}_A||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_1||\vec{v}_A||^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_2||\vec{v}_A||^2
\end{align}

Inspecting the last line reveals that it is zero as well.

\begin{align}
\Delta T_A = \Delta T
\end{align}

#### Intuition

For a more intuitive explanation of why the change in kinetic energy is the same in both frames, imagine where the kinetic energy goes when it is lost. Total energy is conserved, which means that the original kinetic energy of the carts has to appear as energy or work elsewhere. If the carts stick together after the collision, then the carts were probably bent out of shape and hotter than they originally were. It takes work to bend the carts and to add thermal energy. All observers, no matter how they are moving, will see the same about of bending and will measure the same temperature rise. So, since the only source of this work and thermal energy is the original kinetic energy of the carts, and all observers will observe the same amount of bending and thermal energy, they must all observe the same loss of kinetic energy.

#### Extra question

In an accelerating reference frame, nothing is conserved. Objects accelerate due to non-existent (fictitious) forces, so neither momentum nor kinetic energy (nor their changes) are conserved.